# Need help using a terminal command

Tags: make, execute-command

http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=149621
I don't understand how to use make && sudo make install

Comment: Did you read the full post the guy wrote? Anyway to make you need some packages. sudo apt-get install build-essential.

But make && make install, just means after you have downloaded his code, it will compile it. && means new command. It's the same as. make... and then sudo make install in the terminal.

Also, if you have never build anything, you need to read it carefully and not just think you can read half.

Comment: I tried '/home/user/Downloads/folder/<file name>' make which then gave me permission denied

Comment: did you even extract the zip file?

Comment: I did Extract here, that folder and file were already extracted.

Comment: Go into that folder you extraced, right click open terminal here. Type: make && sudo make install

Comment: Whenever I type make it gives me    [make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.]   It doesn't give me the option to open terminal here.

Comment: Then you downloaded the wrong thing..

Comment: did you go into https://github.com/cvuchener/k90-linux-driver/ and press Download?

Comment: I clicked download zip, then I went to downloads and clicked extract here, then I did what it said in the guide and added my product id

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to comple this would be:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/cvuchener/k90-linux-driver.git
cd k90-linux-driver
```

Add the product ID as discussed.

```
make
sudo make install
```

I haven't any idea which Ubuntu version you are running, nor if the package was built correctly for yours. I can test no further.

It does, however, 'make' without error on my 4.4.6-xx kernel.

Comment: You might want to include `build-essential autogen automake  autoconf libtool autoconf* automake ` in your `apt-get install` line.

Comment: I believe `build-essential` includes all that and, moreover, is installed by default in recent Ubutnu versions. Without knowing his version, we don't know if he needs it or not.